# Where is that Rain Juju?

Tags: patapon-2

In "Patapon 2," Gong asks you for the rain juju that is located in Nyokiri Swamp. The problem is, I don't know where it is! Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.gamefaqs.com/psp/950766-patapon-2/answers?qid=69937):

> Go to Nyoriki Swamp Hunting mission, then you will find totem pole called wep. There is Pattern with it(Triangle, Square, And Circle). Follow the pattern on proper rhythm. Don't click anything until it stops spinning. Do this 4x, and the root will give a lot of Kaching and the precious item, the rain miracle.

[The wiki](http://patapon.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Miracles#Rain_Miracle) seems to agree that you have to solve the totem.

> Solve the Wep in Nyokiri Swamp

Comment: This *sounds* right, though it's been years since I got this juju